# What is the meaning of the idiom "no bells and whistles" and an example usage?

Tags: idioms, word-usage

I am looking for some interesting sentences that employ this idiom.

Comment: Please read the [faq]. Asking for a list of usages is not constructive, so not allowed at Stack Exchange. The meaning of "bells and whistles" is available in various [dictionaries](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bells_and_whistles?rdfrom=Bells_and_whistles). Please consult them before asking for the meaning here. If you still have issues once you're consulted a dictionary edit the question to state what you already know and what you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to non-essential but often engaging features added to a piece of technical equipment or a computer program to make it seem more superficially attractive without enhancing its main function"

For example -

1."The digital textbooks that are available have none of the digital bells and whistles that an electronic platform could support."

2."One would think that most chief financial officers, tax executives and business owners take full advantage of all the bells and whistles provided in the United States tax code."